# Laravel ajax store request errormessage, data append to view

Tags: ajax, laravel, request, append

I'm new to ajax and I have two little problems. 
With my code I can write the data in the database. I get no error messages and the data are not synonymous directly loaded into the view.

how can I load the data directly into the view without reload the page? 
if the privacy is 1, the code should be displayed in the right column, and if the privacy is 0, the code should be displayed in the left column.

How can I output the error messages with my errormessage code?

view

```
<div id="content" class="dashboard padding-10">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".todolist-create-modal" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-sm margin-bottom-10">Neue Liste erstellen</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="panel-misc-portlet-l3" class="panel panel-default text-center">
                <div class="panel-heading nohover">
                    <span class="elipsis">
                        <strong>Private Tasks</strong>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger margin-bottom-30 {{ $todolistpublic->count() ? 'hidden' : '' }}">
                Es wurden keine <strong>Einträge</strong> gefunden.
            </div>
            @foreach ($todolistpublic as $list)
                <div id="todo-list-{{$list->id}}" class="panel panel-default panel-primary margin-bottom-0">
                    <div class="panel-heading panel-pointer">
                            <span class="elipsis"><!-- panel title -->
                                <strong>{{ $list->title }}</strong> <span class="label label-info white">0</span>
                            </span>
                        <ul class="options pull-right relative list-unstyled hover-visible">
                            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".task-modal" class="btn btn-success btn-xs white hover-hidden">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Erstellen
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".todolist-modal" data-id="{{ $list->id }}" data-title="{{ $list->title }}" data-description="{{ $list->description }}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs white hover-hidden">
                                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Bearbeiten
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".todolist-delete-modal" data-id="{{ $list->id }}" data-title="{{ $list->title }}" data-description="{{ $list->description }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs white hover-hidden">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Löschen
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="opt panel_colapse" data-placement="bottom"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="slimscroll" data-always-visible="false" data-rail-visible="false" data-railOpacity="1" data-height="100">
                            {{ $list->description }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
            <div class="panel-footer mtm-10">
                <span id="todo-list-counter-public">{{ $todolistpublic->count() }}</span> <span>{{ $todolistpublic->count() > 1? 'Listen' : 'Liste' }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="panel-misc-portlet-l3" class="panel panel-default text-center">
                <div class="panel-heading nohover">
                    <span class="elipsis">
                        <strong>Öffentliche Tasks</strong>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger margin-bottom-30 {{ $todolistprivate->count() ? 'hidden' : '' }}">
                Es wurden keine <strong>Einträge</strong> gefunden.
            </div>
            @foreach ($todolistprivate as $list)
                <div id="todo-list-{{$list->id}}" class="panel panel-default panel-primary margin-bottom-0">
                    <div class="panel-heading panel-pointer">
                            <span class="elipsis"><!-- panel title -->
                                <strong>{{ $list->title }}</strong> <span class="label label-info white">0</span>
                            </span>
                        <ul class="options pull-right relative list-unstyled hover-visible">
                            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".task-modal" class="btn btn-success btn-xs white hover-hidden"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Erstellen</a></li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".todolist-modal" class="btn btn-info btn-xs white hover-hidden"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Bearbeiten</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs white hover-hidden"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Löschen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="opt panel_colapse" data-placement="bottom"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="slimscroll" data-always-visible="false" data-rail-visible="false" data-railOpacity="1" data-height="100">
                            {{ $list->description }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
            <div class="panel-footer mtm-10">
                <span id="todo-list-counter-private">{{ $todolistprivate->count() }}</span> <span>{{ $todolistprivate->count() > 1? 'Listen' : 'Liste' }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        @include('elements.addTodoList')
        @include('elements.createTodoList')
        @include('elements.addTask')
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

        $('#add-todo-list').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val(); // get csrf field.
            var title = $("input[name='title']").val();
            var description = $("textarea[name='description']").val();
            var privacy = $("select[name='privacy']").val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'{{ route('todolists.store') }}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {_token:_token, title:title, description:description, privacy:privacy},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
        });
        });
    });
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|min:5',
        'description' => 'required|min:10',
        'privacy' => 'required|integer'
    ]);

    $attributeNames = array(
        'title' => 'Title',
        'description' => 'Description',
    );
    $validator->setAttributeNames($attributeNames);
    //Redirect back if validation fails
    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
    else{
        $todolists = new Todolists;
        $todolists->admin_id = auth::user();
        $todolists->title = $request->title;
        $todolists->description = $request->description;
        $todolists->privacy = $request->privacy;
        $todolists->save();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Your enquiry has been successfully submitted!']);

    }

}
```

modal

```
<div class="modal fade todolist-create-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Erstelle eine neue Liste</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{{ route('todolists.store') }}" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="control-label">Titelname</label>
                    <div class="fancy-form">
                        <i class="fa fa-header"></i>
                        <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Titel">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="control-label">Beschreibung</label>
                    <div class="fancy-form">
                        <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Beschreibe deine Aufgabe"></textarea>

                        <i class="fa fa-comments"><!-- icon --></i>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="control-label">Privatsphäre</label>
                    <div class="fancy-form fancy-form-select">
                        <select id="privacy" name="privacy" class="form-control">
                            <option selected value="0">Öffentlich</option>
                            <option value="1">Privat</option>
                        </select>
                        <i class="fancy-arrow"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-todo-list">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

errormessages

```
 @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="toastr-notify"></div>
            @foreach ($errors -> all() as $e)
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    _toastr("{{$e}}","top-right","error",false);
                </script>
            @endforeach
@endif

@if (session('fail'))
<div class="toastr-notify"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        _toastr("{{ session('fail') }}","top-full-width","warning",false);
    </script>
@endif

@if (session('status'))
<div class="toastr-notify"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        _toastr("{{ session('status') }}","top-full-width","info",false);
    </script>
@endif

@if (session('success'))
    <div class="btn btn-info toastr-notify"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        _toastr("{{ session('success') }}","top-full-width","success", false);
    </script>
@endif

@if (session('error'))
    <div class="toastr-notify"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        _toastr("{{ session('error') }}","top-full-width","error",false);
    </script>
@endif
```

Comment: Best way would be to start using some PHP debugger extension/software where you could set breakpoints in code having just very good insight what is going on in every line of code. Alternatively, you can check latest message in `storage/logs/laravel.log` file. If file is full of data, you can delete everything from there and make new (AJAX) request. If there error exists (such is 500) it will be written in `storage/logs/laravel.log` file. It will be good start for debugging and fixing the issue.

Comment: I will leave my two cents here that helped me a lot with ajax in the beginning: if you are in Chrome `CTRL + SHIFT + i` and go to `Network` panel. This will show you the ajax requests. You can check the `response` which will give you the error stack and you can better understand the error since it is a 500 (which means you have something wrong in the code)

Comment: try put `$todolists = new Todolists();` and test

Comment: Thanks for the hints, now I finally know how to see the error messages in the browser console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a typo in your ajax backend code; this line to be specific:

```
$todolists->admin_id = auth::user();
```

This should be:

```
$todolists->admin_id = auth()->user()->id;
```

The typo is generating a `Throwable` error, which is getting caught by the laravel exception handler and it's detecting that the code is being executed under a ajax request and hence returning a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that was actually the mistake. Can you please help me with my other questions as well?

Comment: You should create one StackOverflow post per question. anyway, what is your other question?

Comment: i have created a new topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52163545/output-data-and-messages-directly-in-the-view